# ROOKIE ALERT (Learning HTML5/ JavaScript/ CSS from a book): why won't my video file load and play in Firefox (using Win 8, avi/wmv files)?

Tags: html5-video

I get the video control panel but there's no video loaded in the browser. Tried mp3, as well. Coded as follows:

```
video {
    width: 15%; height: auto; float: right; padding: 1rem;
}

<body>
    <video controls>
        <source src="images/Manny4.wmv" type="video/x-ms-wmv">
    </video>
</body>
```

Comment: Original video is from my iphone 11.  WMP is turned on in Control Panel and DirectX Video Acceleration is enabled.

Comment: You can't use **WMV** in a web browser. It's not part of the web standards. **MP4** is the most widely supported video format, so use your video editor (or some online video converter) to change WMV into MP4 then try again on your web page.

Comment: **PS:** I think you got down-votes for _"This Question is not useful or shows lack of research..."_ reasons (move mouse to the "down" voting arrow to see reasons). You can check supported video formats at [Can-I-Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=video%20format) (green means supported by that browser). **MP3** does not work in video tag, use same tested MP3 in an `<audio>` tag and it will play ok.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and other browsers do not support WMV videos. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Converted file to webm format and it worked, therefore, i accept it as a solution.  I'm still trying to learn protocols; I will do better in the future.

Comment: Please accept your answer as solution 